# Delegating command line arguments to another commands

Tags: python, argparse, python-module

I need some Python module to support forwarding command line arguments to other commands.

`argparse` allows to parse arguments easily, but doesn't deliver any "deparsing" tool.

I could just forward `os.sys.argv` if I hadn't need to delete or change values of any of them, but I have.

I can imagine myself a class that just operates on array of strings all the time, without losing any information, but I failed finding any.

Does somebody know such tool or maybe met similar problem and found out another nice way to handle?

(Sorry for English :()

Comment: I am a little confused about your question can you give an example of a command you want to forward?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, so this suggestion is only a guess, but you can try `getopt` module to work with command line arguments on lower level.

Comment: `./bin/Program --arg1 val1 --arg2 val2 --arg3 val3.1 val3.2 val3.3 --arg4 --arg5 val5 ... --arg10 val10`
`Program` has to execute some instances of `ProgramWorker`:
`./bin/ProgramWorker --arg1 val1 --arg2 newVal --arg3 val3.1 --arg4 --arg6 ... --arg10 val10 --arg11`

Delegating arguments from paralleled application to its workers that are independent applications with their own interfaces - that's pretty good description of what I need to do.

@marbu Thank you, I'll check this out.

Comment: Look in the `argparse` documentation for `parse_known_args`.  This lets you parse some arguments, and save the rest for use by other functions and/or processes.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `subprocess` module to run the commands with delegated arguments you can specify your command as a list of strings that won't be subject to shell parsing (as long as you don't use `shell=True`). You therefore don't need to bother about quoting concerns the same way you would if you were reconstructing a command line. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments for further details.